# Repeating function until the screen is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsivevoice

I am using this src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js" (TTS) and i want to make 3 messages to be played in a loop until user clicks somewhere on screen.

3 messages are played, with some kind of interval between them,first ..interval..second....interval...third... repeat untill click ,  they are repeating until screen is pressed, any ideas ? tried this but failed

```
var text1 = "This is the first message";
        var text2 = "This is the second message";
        var text3 = "This is the third message";
        var text4 = "This is the fourth message";
    function toggleThem()
{
    window.setTimeout(function(){
            responsiveVoice.speak(text1);
        }, 200);
         window.setTimeout(function(){
            responsiveVoice.speak(text2);
        },2000 );
         window.setTimeout(function(){
            responsiveVoice.speak(text3);
        }, 2500);
}
toggleThem();
```

Comment: don't use timeout, use events

Comment: why not setInterval and removeInterval as per the condition

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` to make your spoken text cycle until the window is clicked:

```js
var text1 = "This is the first message";
var text2 = "This is the second message";
var text3 = "This is the third message";
var text4 = "This is the fourth message";

function speak (text) {
  console.log('Speaking: ', text)
  responsiveVoice.speak(text)
}

function toggleThem() {
  setTimeout(speak, 200, text1)
  setTimeout(speak, 2000, text2)
  setTimeout(speak, 2500, text3)
  setTimeout(speak, 3000, text4)
}

var interval = setInterval(toggleThem, 3500)

window.addEventListener('click', function handler() {
  clearInterval(interval)
  this.removeEventListener('click', handler)
})
```

```html
<script src="http://code.responsivevoice.org/responsivevoice.js"></script>
```

Comment: Didn't really work, my goal is when user presses the screen (anywhere) speaking stops immediately. And while playing it should play all text that is written